# Highlight text on image, similar to google translate app

Tags: android, image, text, selection, highlight

In google translate app in android, there is photo search section. After taking a photo, user can select a text using highlighting effect. Is there a way to reproduce this effect easily manually?  Alternatively, is there a library that can be used for this? (I am only interested in the text selection part.)

Comment: Have you ever found any option for this?

Answer (score 0):

The stock camera app has image cropping, you can extract the code and use it in your own app. It is (or at least was last time I checked) just a few classes. You can also invoke it via an intent, but then your app would depend on the stock camera app being available, and might break in future Android version if they decide to remove or change the intent action, etc.

Comment: I know the crop intent but this is not what I wanted actually. I think this method is more effective than cropping... Thanks for reply btw

Comment: It is effectively the same: you select what part of the image to submit to OCR. It might look nicer, but that's it.

Comment: But if there are more than one word you can select individually. For example if you have 2 rows you can select 1 word from first row and another from the other...

Comment: That must be a new version then. This is not trivial, so I doubt you will find a ready made solution.

Comment: @kaanB I'm looking for the same thing. I could not find any.

Comment: @GordonSun, I couldn't find it either.